# Embedding two BrowserComponent inside a form, using custom size

Tags: codenameone

How can I set a custom height for the BrowserComponent, as to be able to embed two Browser Components inside a form?

For example, I need to have a BrowserView with a height of 50px and another filling the rest of the screen. I tried using the available layouts... But no matters which, a single browsed component is showed filling the entire screen.

What can I do? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this. I suggest not hardcoding with pixel sizes (although that's possible) but instead relying on screen percentage which is a better approach on devices.

```
TableLayout tl = new TableLayout(2, 1);
Form f = new Form("2 Browsers", tl);
f.setScrollable(false);
f.add(tl.cc().hp(5).wp(100), browser1);
f.add(tl.cc().hp(95), browser2);
```

In the code above:

- `cc` == `createConstraint`
- `hp` == `heightPercentage`
- `wp` == `widthPercentage`

I did several things here. First I disabled the form scrolling (which is on by default) so the browsers builtin native scrolling will be used instead.

Second I added the browsers with fixed height constraint, this made sure their `preferredSize` value is ignored for the Y axis.

Since they are both in the same column I only had to define the width of the first browser but I'm not sure I even need that. I did that just to be safe.